# Create Excel Add-in - get cell value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, c#-4.0, add-in

I am creating a excel Add-in using visual studio 2010. I was able to get the cell address using this code.

```
label1.Label = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Address.ToString();
```

I want to get the cell value. Also if you can tell me how to set a value for a given cell.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get a cell value for the active cell the following should do it

```
var cellValue = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.ActiveCell.Value.ToString()
```

or for a specific cell

```
var cellValue = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.Cells("A1").Value.ToString()
```

To Set the value it is basically the reverse

```
Globals.MyAddIn.Application.Cells("A1").Value = "ABC123"
```

**EDIT**
Try this.  I know that this works as I have something like it working in my own addin.

```
int row = 1;
int col = 1;
var sheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
sheet1.Cells[row, col] = "ABC123";

string cellValue = sheet1.Cells[row,col];
```

Comment: but can't set a value **Error 1 Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application.Cells' cannot be used like a method.** Please help

Comment: also can't take specific cell value {var cellValue = Globals.MyAddIn.Application.Cells("A1").Value.ToString()}