# Set value of cell in add in

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-addins

I will explain everything that I have found but in short I just **want to set the value of cell A1 in code behind**. I have tried [Create Excel Add-in - get cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550726/create-excel-add-in-get-cell-value) plus other links and all those techniques work only if I run them on a macro but I want execute them from a function.

So let me start explaining:

I do not understand why I get a wierd behaviour when I run the same code on a function versus a Sub. Take the following example:

```
Dim TimeToRun

Sub Macro1()

    'Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    'Dim automationObject As Object
    'Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ProbeAddIn")
    'Set automationObject = addIn.Object

    'automationObject.ImportData

    MsgBox "Hello world"

End Sub

Sub Macro2()

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Macro1" ' run Macro1 on 1 seconds

End Sub


Function Test()

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "Macro1" ' run Macro1 on 1 seconds

End Function
```

Note that `Macro2` and function `Test` have the same code. Why is it that if I run Macro2 it works ok (message box shows up). But if I go to a a cell and type `=Test()` then I get an error even though I have the same code !

The reason why am I showing this example is because the code that I have commented out on Macro1 works great if I run it by running the macro directly. If I place that code inside the function Test it does not work. That code is executing the following method in my add-in project on visual studio:

[image]

The exception is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146827284   Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>   Source=""   ErrorCode=-2146827284   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes,
>   MessageData& msgData)
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Value2(Object value)
>          at ReadWrite.ImportData() in C:\Users\Antonio\Dropbox_Temp\visual studio\Probe add in
>   test\ProbeAddIn\ProbeAddIn\Class1.cs:line 82   InnerException:

I got that exception because I ran:

```
Function Test()

    Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ProbeAddIn")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object                

    automationObject.ImportData

End Function
```

Instead of

```
Sub Test()

    Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ProbeAddIn")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object

    automationObject.ImportData

End Function
```

How can I make the code inside a macro and function run the same way? I want to trigger the execution of that method when user types in a formula not when the user runs a macro. **Even if I have the function run the macro I get the same exception** The only way I do not get an exception is if the first thing that runs is a macro...

Comment: Excel VBA Sub doesn't return, but a Function does. So your `Function Test` doesn't...

Comment: what about the last `Function Test()`? that one returns. It calls the ImportData method. That method is not able to change the value of cell A1 why? If I run that same method from a macro it works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What you really want to do, make an add-in to change the cell value on a particular time? after every second?

Comment: I have a board: http://am.renesas.com/products/tools/introductory_evaluation_tools/renesas_demo_kits/yrdkrx63n/index.jsp  I am able to read the value of a variable. I want to read the value every 500 milliseconds. I am able to do it with a macro but I will like to create a function in excel that does that. The signature of my method looks like `Read(memAddress as String, numberOfBytesToRead as integer)`

Comment: Variable? or cell value? Can you please show us your current macro? Why are you using `range1.Value2`? why not `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but the issue you have may be due to the fact that when your function is fired the Excel application is in **edit mode** and so cannot accept any input from outside hence the exception when you try to insert data.

If you want to update a cell in a continuous way in a clean manner what you need is a **RTD server**.

From your cells you will simply call :

```
=RTD("my.super.rtdserver",,"mydata")
```

From time to time your **RTD server** will notify Excel of new data and lets Excel **call-back** to retrieve them when it is ready.